# QTextEdit focusOut programmatically doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qmouseevent

I have a custom **QTextEdit** which overrides `::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)` and `::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e)`. The context of QTextEdit is selectable. In **selection mode**, when the **user exceeds QTextEdit's bounds** I want to **stop the selection programmatically** by doing this in ::mouseMoveEvent:

```
if(e->pos().y() < 0)
{
    QTextEdit::focusOutEvent(new QFocusEvent(QFocusEvent::FocusOut));
}
```

I figured out that when the user releases the mouse, focusOutEvent is being called immediately.

**The problem**: Even though I call focusOutEvent programmatically, the focusOutEvent is not called at all. It is called only when the user releases the mouse click. I tried also with mouseReleaseEvent but it's the same problem.

Why the focusOutEvent is not called? What can be done? And if there is another solution to my problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling:

```
 QTextEdit::focusOutEvent(new QFocusEvent(QFocusEvent::FocusOut));
```

Did you tried invoking:

```
clearFocus ();
```